# PDF - Open Bookmarks Panel when pdf opens

Tags: vba, pdf, acrobat

When I open a certain pdf file on SharePoint, I wish to see the Bookmarks Navigation tab open by default. I can do this manually by File > Properties > initial View and changing the Navigation tab to "Bookmarks Panel and Page".
I need to do this with hundreds of pdf files and then upload them to SharePoint.
I am using VBA. I don't mind using other forms of automation.

Currently, I have AVDoc (CAcroAVDoc) and can open the Bookmarks Pane but it's not changed in the settings.
AVDoc.SetViewMode 3
I tried PDDoc.SetInfo etc but nothings changing the "settings".

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

I am running a lot of code in Excel VBA, that does a lot of pdf manipulation. The only thing that remains is to change the settings.

Answer (score 0):

With Acrobat as the runtime, there is no scriptable interface to the initial view settings. However, you can easily use any of several .NET PDF libraries to make this change. A Google search for ".NET PDF Library" will yield both free and commercial varieties. You'll need to research which one is best for your task and skill set.